# Implementing colspan on DIVS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div layout like this
 Style

```
.l-item{
    display:inline-block; 
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    width:20px;
    height:20px
}  


<div id="head">
   <div>
       <div class="l-item">a</div>
       <div class="l-item">a</div>
       <div class="l-item">a</div>
       <div class="l-item">a</div>
       <div class="l-item">b</div>
       <div class="l-item">b</div>
   </div>
   <div>
       <div class="l-item">x</div>
       <div class="l-item">y</div>
       <div class="l-item">z</div>
       <div class="l-item">z</div>
       <div class="l-item">z</div>
       <div class="l-item">x</div>
   </div>
   <div>
       <div class="l-item">1</div>
       <div class="l-item">2</div>
       <div class="l-item">3</div>
       <div class="l-item">4</div>
       <div class="l-item">4</div>
       <div class="l-item">4</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

My requirement is to merge similar valued and sibling DIVS into single DIV as colspan. For that I have an approach like below

```
$('#head > div').each(function(){
    $(this).find('.l-item').each(function(){
         var txt = $(this).text();
         $(this).siblings().filter(function(){
             return $(this).text() == txt;
         });
    });
});
```

It seems like it will mess with the DOM, any other solution for this please..

Comment: USE a grid framework like http://960.gs

Comment: I am not open to use a framework for this single requiremnt @AdityaSaxena

Comment: It would be best served if you DID use grid frameworks. For "this single requirement" is good enough IMO to use a grid framework. Also, the 960gs is not so big either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/rnL3h/

**JS:-**

```
$('#head > div').each(function () {
    $(this).find('.l-item').each(function () {
        var txt = $(this).text();
        var items = $(this).siblings().filter(function () {
            return $(this).text() == txt;
        });
        if (items.length > 0) {
            $(this).width($(this).width() * (items.length + 1));            
            items.remove();
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little bit of help to get you started: http://jsfiddle.net/WeJmu

```
$('#head > div').each(function(){
    $(this).find('.l-item').each(function(){
        var txt = $(this).text();
        var num_eaten = 0;
        $(this).siblings().each(function () {
            if ($(this).text() === txt) {
                num_eaten++;
                $(this).remove();
            }
        });

        if (num_eaten > 0) {
            $(this).width($(this).width() * (num_eaten + 1));
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

different approach with [next](http://api.jquery.com/next/), you can develop it with better way. [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5Bu2L/)

```
$('#head > div').each(function(){
    $(this).find('.l-item').each(function(){
         var txt = $(this).text();
         if( $(this).next().text() == txt){
            $(this).next().width($(this).next().width() + 20);
            $(this).remove();   
         }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

if by appearance you want consecutive divs with same text to look like a single div/column;

http://jsfiddle.net/WeJmu/2/

```
$('#head > div').each(function(){
$(".l-item").each(function(){
    var $this=$(this);
    var $next=$(this).next();
    if( $this.text()==$next.text()){
        $this.css({'border-right':'none'});
        $next.css({'border-left':'none'});
    }

});
});
```